# Split labels in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, split, layout-manager, jtabbedpane

I need to change my label's distribution on a JTabbedPane.

I have this:

[image]
And I want to do this:
[image]
Can someone help me?

I post the code below:

```
 tabbedResultsPane = new JTabbedPane(SwingConstants.TOP);

     JPanel featurePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(TOTAL_FEATURES, 2, 3, 3));  
     estadoScroll = new JScrollPane(featurePanel,
                      JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                      JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        lblFeatureHdr = new JLabel[TOTAL_FEATURES];
        lblFeature = new JLabel[TOTAL_FEATURES];
        for(int i=0; i<TOTAL_FEATURES; i++)
        {
           lblFeatureHdr[i] = new JLabel(strHeader[i], JLabel.RIGHT);
           lblFeatureHdr[i].setOpaque(true);  
           lblFeatureHdr[i].setBackground(new Color(220,255,220));//.lightGray);

           lblFeature[i] = new JLabel("", JLabel.LEFT);
           lblFeature[i].setForeground(Color.blue);// black); 

           featurePanel.add(lblFeatureHdr[i]);
           featurePanel.add(lblFeature[i]);                
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Define 4 columns GridLayout (rather than 2 columns you have).

and correct your code yo add 2 more labels for each row.

```
for(int i=0; i<TOTAL_FEATURES; i++)
    {
       lblFeatureHdr[i] = new JLabel(strHeader[i], JLabel.RIGHT);
       lblFeatureHdr[i].setOpaque(true);  
       lblFeatureHdr[i].setBackground(new Color(220,255,220));//.lightGray);

       lblFeature[i] = new JLabel("", JLabel.LEFT);
       lblFeature[i].setForeground(Color.blue);// black); 

       featurePanel.add(lblFeatureHdr[i]);
       featurePanel.add(lblFeature[i]);  
       // add 2 more lables to the same row    
       JLabel l=new JLabel(strHeader[i], JLabel.RIGHT);
       l.setBackground(new Color(220,255,220));//.lightGray);          
       featurePanel.add(l);
       featurePanel.add(new JLabel("", JLabel.LEFT));                
    }
```

Comment: it is close, but with your code I loose the green background on the third column, can you help me a bit more?

Comment: Code updated. In fact you can generate desired JLabel instance and apply all the styles as to the first JLabel in the array.

Comment: it doesn't work, i have one column green but the others are white

Comment: *"it doesn't work"*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).